# Incomplete type error when store an array of T in the struct T

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Why this is allowed:

```cpp
// 1
struct S {
    std::vector<S> v;
};

// 2
struct T {
    T* ptr;
};
```

and this is not:

```cpp
// 3
struct X {
    X arr[];
};
```

Here is the error for the third example (`clang-1001.0.46.3` compiler):

```
sample.cpp:9:4: error: field has incomplete type 'X'
        X arr[];
          ^
sample.cpp:8:8: note: definition of 'X' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct X {
       ^
```

I understand the reason why array of fixed size is not allowed in the struct, that's because `sizeof(T) = sizeof(T)*array_size + size_of_other_members`, btw it compiles fine with `std::vector<T>`, but doesn't compile with `T[]`.

Comment: `vector` is a `T*`, not a `T[]`.

Comment: arrays of fixed size are allowed in the struct, but `X arr[];` is not an array of fixed size, without specifying size type of this field is incomplete, moreover it is not possible to create recursive structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a variable to be defined the compiler needs to know the size of the variable.

In the first case what you have are pointers to `S` (remember that `std::vector` allocates memory dynamically of the heap, and therefore only need a pointer), which is okay because the compiler knows the size of pointers.

In the second case when you use `X` the type (structure) isn't fully defined yet, so the compiler doesn't know the size of `X` yet. Furthermore in C++ you can't have "empty" arrays, all arrays must have a compile-time fixed size.

Comment: But that doesn't fail during compilation: `struct X { int arr[]; X() : arr{1} {} X(int) : arr{1, 2} {} };`

Comment: @J.S. When you use an initializer list in the constructor, it's equivalent to doing e.g. `int arr[] = { 1 }`, which is allowed because then the compiler knows the size of the array (it's the size of the initializer list).

Comment: @J.S. This code snippet is not valid and should not compile. There are "flexible arrays" in C99 but they are not a thing in C++.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `Flexible array member`, it was introduced in `c99` standard of the C programming language.
So in `C` following is possible,

```
struct IntContainer
{
  size_t length;
  int arr[];
};
```

But `C++` does not have flexible array members.
For more information please see following, [Flexible array member - wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)